# What is the meaning of 中途半端な時間 in this context

Tags: meaning

I came across the following dialogue in manga where a guy is apologizing to a girl.

> A: さっきは責めるようなこと言って悪かったな。
>
> B: ...は！？　まだ諦めてなかったの？...っていうか。この中途半端な時間から...
>
> A: いいからいいから！あと一回だけオレに付き合ってくれ！

I've been searching everywhere but can't find something that explains what 中途半端な時間 means in this context. Literally it translates to something like "from this half-assed time" which makes no sense. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

中途半端な時間 usually refers the time between meals, i.e. non-mealtime. The following line goes:

> いいからいいから！あと一回だけオレに付き合ってくれ！
> C'mon! C'mon! Come with me just one more time!

The context doesn't make it clear if this is an invitation to lunch/dinner, but it most likely is. That is why the other person, B, says この中途半端な時間から...

So A invites B to lunch/dinner. But it's not usual lunchtime or dinnertime, so B's objection is "wait, at this hour?" And that is responded to with A's persuasive いいから！ and あと一回だけオレに付き合ってくれ！

---

Edit: Per @naruto's comment, the phrase 中途半端な時間 itself has broader meanings.

Comment: That's right! It is an invitation to lunch actually! And your translation makes total sense. However I'm still not sure what the から at the end is supposed to be doing there lol.

Comment: @leosan Have you heard people say 今から? Like 今から寝ます = I'm going to bed now. Time + から indicates an action is going to take place starting at that time.

Comment: This happens to be correct since the context is related to lunch, but 中途半端な時間 refers to a bit unusual/inconvenient time for doing something in general. 中途半端な時間に目が覚めた may refer to, say, 4:30 am, and 中途半端な時間に昼食を食べたからまだおなかが空いてない may refer to 15:00. Of course you cannot eat lunch between meals.